# IE error 'Style' is null or not an object - lightbox-resize.js

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

in Ie I am getting a javascript error:

'Style' is null or not an object 
lightbox-resize.js 
Line 33
char 6
code 0

This realates to the following page:

http://www.nickypellegrino.com/blog/

I can figure out what is causing this issue. The page (and the lightbox) works fine in firefox/chrome - but not in IE.

There is also another error being thrown about prototype.js, and I don't know what that is either :P

Comment: The page throws exceptions in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

The problem stems from the collision between Prototype and jQuery over the symbol "$".  You're going to have to make one or the other of them relinquish it.

With jQuery, you do it like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

right after including the library:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Once you've done that, all the code that expects "$" to mean "jQuery" will have to explicitly use the global name "jQuery" instead of "$".

A better solution would probably be to find a way to avoid using two large JavaScript frameworks on the same page. Both of them have large ecosystems, so it's very likely you can find the tools you need and only rely on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using prototype.js and jQuery without using jQuery's [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), what results in a conflict when using `$()`